# Why the kendoDatePicker is disabled in modal bootstrap

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm doing an asp.net mvc project and I have a view as below:

```
 <div class="content-wrapper">
         <div class="bs-example wow fadeInUp animated" data-wow-delay=".5s" data-example-id="contextual-table" style="border: 1px solid #eee">
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="">
                    <tr style="background-color: #555555; color: white">

                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.contractId)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Customer.IdentificationNo)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Device.DeviceId)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Vehicle.Vin)
                        </th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>

                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.contractId)
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Customer.IdentificationNo)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Device.DeviceId)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Vehicle.Vin)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a class="anchorDetail btn btn-1 btn-info" onclick="ContractDetail(@item.Id)">جزئیات</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }

                </table>
            </div>
        </div>


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLable">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="myModalLable">Modal title</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="myModalBody">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<script>
    function ContractDetail(Id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Contract/EditContract/",
            type: "Get",
            data: { Id: Id }
        }).done(function (result) {
            $("#myModal").modal();
            $("#myModalLable").html("ویرایش قرارداد");
            $("#myModalBody").html(result);
        });
    }
</script>
```

I wanna call an action with the jquery function in this view. The action is as below:

```
public ActionResult EditContract(int Id)
    {
        if (Id == 0)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Contract contract = db.Contract.Where(c => c.Id == Id && c.IsDeleted != true).Select(c => c).SingleOrDefault();

        if (contract == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return PartialView("EditContract", contract);
    }
```

As you see this action returns a partialview. The partial view is as below:

```
    @model DataLayer.Contract
    @{
        Layout = null;
    }

    <body class="hold-transition register-page">
        <div class="register-box">
            <div class="register-logo">
                <b>ویرایش قرارداد</b>
            </div>

            <div class="register-box-body">


                @using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditContract", "Contract", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions()
                {
                    OnSuccess = "success",
                    UpdateTargetId = "listUsers"

                }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IsDeleted)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Fr_CustomerId)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Fr_DeviceId)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Fr_VehicleId)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CustomerIdentificationNo)


                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 row">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @disabled = "true", @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 row">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PublicId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PublicId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @disabled = "true", @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PublicId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 row">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreateDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreateDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @disabled = "true", @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreateDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 row">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RegistererUser, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RegistererUser, new { htmlAttributes = new { @disabled = "true", @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RegistererUser, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 row">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.C_key, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.C_key, new { htmlAttributes = new { @disabled = "true", @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.C_key, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 row">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.C_id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.C_id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @disabled = "true", @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.C_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 row">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.C_rev, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.C_rev, new { htmlAttributes = new { @disabled = "true", @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.C_rev, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 row">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.contractId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.contractId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @disabled = "true", @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.contractId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 row">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.deviceId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.deviceId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @disabled = "true", @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.deviceId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 row">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.vehicleId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.vehicleId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @disabled = "true", @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.vehicleId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 row">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.vid, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.vid, new { htmlAttributes = new { @disabled = "true", @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.vid, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 row">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cid, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.cid, new { htmlAttributes = new { @disabled = "true", @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cid, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 row">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.did, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.did, new { htmlAttributes = new { @disabled = "true", @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.did, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 row">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerIdentificationNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerIdentificationNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @disabled = "true", @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerIdentificationNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.StartTime) } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.EndTime) } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartMilage, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.StartMilage) } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartMilage, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.state, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.state) } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.state, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <a class="btn btn-warning" id="EditContract">ویرایش قرارداد</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger" id="DeleteContract">پاک کردن قرارداد</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-normal">بروز رسانی</a>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>






    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.918/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.2.918/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#StartTime").kendoDatePicker();
        $("#EndTime").kendoDatePicker();
    });
</script>
```

While the modal is appeared why the calendar of the kendoDatePicker won't be opened in the modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in jquery version. My problem is solved by changing the

```
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

into

```
 <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.min.js">
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a timing issue with the JS. You need to run the datepicker code after the modal loads:

```
...
$("#myModalBody").html(result);

// initialize kendo elements on partial
$("#StartTime").kendoDatePicker();
$("#EndTime").kendoDatePicker();
```

Comment: It is not possible, because the html tags for modal and the jquery function that calls the action and puts the result of the action in the modal are in my first view page, and the jquery function for kendoDatePicker is in my second view page. How can I do what you say?

Comment: The modal partial view is rendered on your view (at #myModal), so after it renders, run the kendo js. Did you try it?

Comment: The proble was in jquery version. My problem is solved by changing the   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>   into   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.min.js"></script>